# The name 'ninja' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, .net, cucumber

With the below code I get thee following error:
NinjaSteps.cs(16,13): error CS0103: The name 'ninja' does not exist in the current context

The command line I use to compile is:
`csc /target:library /reference:C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\
cuke4nuke-0.4.0\dotnet\Cuke4Nuke.Framework.dll /reference:C:\Fitnesse\FitNesseRo
ot\jediwhale-fitsharp-a78d820\binary\tools\nunit\framework\nunit.framework.dll /
reference:C:\Users\Rahul\Documents\Visual~1\Projects\ConsoleApplication3\Console
Application3\Ninja.dll NinjaSteps.cs`

The code I am trying to compile is from a tutorial on Cucumber automation technology:

NinjaSteps.cs:

http://cuke4ninja.com/sec_ninja_survival_net.html

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Cuke4Nuke.Framework;
using NUnit.Framework;
using NinjaSurvivalRate;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class NinjaSteps
    {   [Given(@"^the ninja has a ([a-z]*) level black-belt$")]
        public void TheNinjaHasABlackBelt(String level)
        {   ninja = new Ninja(level);
        }

        [When(@"^attacked by [a\s]*(.*)$")]
        public void AttackedBy(String opponent)
        {
            actions = ninja.AttackedBy(opponent);
        }

        [Then("^the ninja should (.*)$")]
        public void TheNinjaShould(String action)
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(actions.Contains(action));
        }

    }
}
```

Ninja.cs is below, compiled to Ninja.dll:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace NinjaSurvivalRate
{
    public class Ninja
    {
        public Ninja(String beltLevel)
        {

        }
        public List<String> AttackedBy(String opponent)
        {
            if ("Chuck Norris" == opponent)
                return new List<string>(
                  new String[] { "run for his life" });
            else
                return new List<string>(
                  new String[] { "engage the opponent" });
        }
    }
}
```

Answers and feedback will be appreciated. Going through similar threads, I found that the resolution depended on a case by case basis and their was no consistent root cause, and felt I had to detail exact code details to get an understanding of the cause. You time and help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined the variable `ninja`. You need:

```
var ninja = new Ninja(level);
```

Do the same for actions.

EDIT:

Actually both the variables are supposed to be fields/properties in the class itself, if I understand your intentions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial is not telling you the whole history. If you go to the [source code](https://github.com/davedf/cuke4ninja/blob/master/src/dotnet/NinjaSurvivalRate/src/NinjaSteps.cs) you will see that there is actually a field `ninja` declared that is initialized in the method `TheNinjaHasABlackBelt` (that you already have).